# How to escape quotations in laravel config after app_path() to correctly read a file path?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to read a file using a path from my config file in app/config/local/myconfig.php but I am unable to read the file path correctly.

myconfig.php:

```
<?php

return array(

    'myfile' => 'app_path() . "/database/data/file.txt"'

);
```

I have tried switching the quotations to tick marks but I still keep getting an error that it is not able to find the file. I would like to keep `app_path()` at the beginning if possible.

What can I do to be able to properly read the file path from my config?

Comment: You need to remove the quotes surrounding the value. Anything within single quotes `'` will be treated as a string and will not be parsed by the interpreter, so the `app_path()` function will not be executed. Your configuration line should look like this `'myfile' => app_path() . "/database/data/file.txt"`. There's no real need to define an extra `$path` variable as in @yaa110's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function name and concatenation `.` operator are similar to simple characters inside `''`, i.e. you are passing a simple string of *app_path() . "/database/data/file.txt"*. Remove `''` of value or use this code:

```
$path = app_path() . "/database/data/file.txt";
return array(
    'myfile' => $path
);
```